# how to mock object created via require

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, mocha.js

I'm new to node.js and in most code I've seen I don't see IoC/DI style constructor injection of dependencies.

Instead, typically the node.js extension require() is used to create local vars allowing access to external modules' exports.

But when writing unit-tests ( that isolate single layer/function ), how to mock the modules accessed via vars created with require ?

```
/helpers/dataHelper.js

var dataModel = require('../models/dataModel.js');

var getFormattedDataForRegion = function(region, callback) {
    var data = {};
    // validate region
    // query dataModel
    // async.map format data items
    // callback(data);
}

/tests/dataHelperTests.js

describe('dataHelper', function(){

    it('getFormattedDataForRegion returns expected response', function(done){

        var expectedData = {};
        // populate expectedData

        // **** need some way to mock dataModel *****

        dataHelper.getFormattedDataForRegion("west", function(data){
            expect(data).to.eql(expectedData);
            done();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).

I personally don't like the technique, but it's the best way that I've found to respect the "node way" and still be able to test easily. You'd do:

```
var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire'),
    dataModelMock = require('./mocks/dataModel');

proxyquire('path/to/helpers/dataHelper.js', { '../models/dataModel.js': dataModelMock });
```

Comment: ok i've figured out how to stub module functions via `proxyquire` but only a single generic stub for any args passed-in.  how can i stub specific return values for specific args values ?  ( as is commonly done with moq , rhino )

Comment: apparently with `proxyquire` to go beyond trivial stubs you must create an entirely mock module.  my module has a property instantiated as an instance of a function that has prototype functions, so i need to stub `myModule.myProperty.read(id)`.  can this be done with `proxyquire` without coding a `mockMyModule` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar you seem to need something like [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/). Check out their "Features at a glance" section (almost bottom of the home page).